# Function is expecting arrays but I want to pass a variable

Tags: php, arrays, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a PHP function that is expecting an unknown number of arrays as parameters.

```
function cartesianProduct() { ... }
```

It is expecting me to do something like this:

```
cartesianProduct(
  array('blue', 'green', 'red'),
  array('apples', 'oranges', 'bananas')  
);
```

But I'm constructing the arrays beforehand and am having trouble passing them in.
For example:

```
$arrs = array(
  array('blue', 'green', 'red'),
  array('apples', 'oranges', 'bananas')
);
cartesianProduct($arrs);
```

Passing in the arrays this way doesn't work - obviously it is seeing it as one single array parameter.

How can I 'expand' my `$arrs` parameter or call the function in a different way to make the function think I'm passing the inner arrays?

Thanks

Comment: Looking at that - yes, a duplicate. I didn't know how to explain myself though.

Comment: It's okay.  Just for the future people should hit that question since it's more generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) to accomplish that.

```
$arrs = array(
    array('blue', 'green', 'red'),
    array('apples', 'oranges', 'bananas')
);

call_user_func_array('cartesianProduct', $arrs);
```

The first argument is the function name you want to call and the second is an indexed array of parameters that will be passed to it.